# EntityFramework.5.0.0: Failed to initialize the Powershell host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

On Creating Entity Model  from database it gives the following error Using VS 2012
I googled it but did not find any answer 
Please help me in fixing my Problem

error is
 EntityFramework.5.0.0: Failed to initialize the Powershell host. If your powershell execution      policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the package manager console to initialize the host   first.
jQuery.1.7.1.1: Failed to initialize the Powershell host. If your powershell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the package manager console to initialize the host first.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You should manually install an update 2.8.7 for NuGet Packet Managet.

Link to download from GitHub: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases/download/2.8.7/NuGet.Tools.vsix

Description of this issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/974

Comment: Question is marked as 2010 and it doesn't installing in my 2010. Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Powershell 2.0.

> During installation if you get an error cannot copy
>   windowsremotemanagement.adm,  remove group policy folder in
>   **c:/windows/system32**, you will have to first changhe folder options to
>   show hidden files and folders then right click on grouppolicy folder
>   and go to **security/advanced/owner**, get a ownership and check select for
>   all files and sub folders. So you can delete it

To refresh group policy run->cmd->gpupdate force

Comment: Still Getting the same error i followed all the instructions but having the same problem :(